# pm2 is restarting many times when setup on port 80

Tags: node.js, pm2

I deployed a node project on port 80. when I run `"sudo node index.js"` then project work fine but when i run `"pm2 start index.js"`', it  restart many times. anyone have idea about this problem

Comment: Add more details to the question, is there an error while restarting?

Comment: No just increase restart count when run pm2 list

Comment: Check the logs using `pm2 logs` to check the exact error.

Comment: try `sudo pm2 start index.js`